# Function script on Google Spreadsheets is too slow

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I've gotten this code to add one to a number in a cell from Google's Spreadsheet but it's taking too long to execute, like 5~15 seconds on average.  My sheet does not have much data, it's about 30X15.

The code is like this below. It's been called by a button inside the sheet.

```
function plus1() {
    var activeCell = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getActiveCell();
    var currentValue = activeCell.getValue();

    activeCell.setValue(currentValue + 1);
}
```

The execution transcript below:

```
[19-05-07 04:29:35:609 PDT] Starting execution
[19-05-07 04:29:35:620 PDT] SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet() [0 seconds]
[19-05-07 04:29:35:621 PDT] Spreadsheet.getActiveCell() [0 seconds]
[19-05-07 04:29:36:233 PDT] Range.getValue() [0.611 seconds]
[19-05-07 04:29:36:295 PDT] Range.setValue([3.0]) [0.061 seconds]
[19-05-07 04:29:36:620 PDT] Execution succeeded [0.678 seconds total runtime]
```

It'd be better to have the coding finishing below 3 secs every time. 
What could I do to improve that time? Thank you all for helping!

Comment: I suggest that you look at the Execution Transcript (from the Script editor - View, Execution Transcript) to identify where the script is spending its time - and add the transcript to your question (its only 6 lines). I just ran your script in a big spreadsheet (though a sheet with little data) and it took 0.3 seconds. Of that, `getValue` was 0.2 seconds.

Comment: I just updated the question with the transcript.
The code seems to run pretty fast but the number isn't been update like this.

Comment: I'm taking it as read that there are no other scripts running, or complex arithmetic, other sheets in the spreadsheet, etc, etc. The `getValue` time _does_ appear high. I suggest that next time you experience a "long" execution time, then check the execution transcript immediately, update the question accordingly , and leave a new comment.

Comment: I got a big delay today but when I checked the execution transcript it had about the same time as before. I think the problem isn't the code but something else. What do you think it could be?

Comment: Any other code, custom functions, data import, etc? How long does the spreadsheet take to recalculate? You need to share your spreadsheet.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
SpreadsheetApp.flush();
```

To the end of your script for faster updating.